# Datepicker falls behind active button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have problems with my datepicker script. When I use bootstraps 'active' on a button, it ends up on top of my datepicker instead of behind. I have tried messing around with the z-index, but I haven't got it to work.

Can it be some setting I haven't understood in datepicker?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/539Xh/

```
<script> 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Added this mainly because I had to have code with jsfiddle.
</script>
```

PS. I've tried with Firefox 31.0 and IE 9.0.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the z-index and position css for the datepicker, like so:

```
.datepicker {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

## JsFiddle

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! How stupid of me to forget the positioning! Thank you very much, I'll accept the answer in a few minutes (when I can)!